# Dynamic Select Option isn't binding Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular-directive, ngfor

I'm developing a select option dependent of another one. In this case, the user select the country and after the cities of this country is loaded. I've looked some examples on the internet but it still doesn't work. The first select option works well, thats mean, the list of countries appears correctly. But the second one, when I select a specific country, doesn't show the related cities.

View code:

```
<div class="input-field col s6 m3 l3">
    <select materialize="material_select" formControlName="country" (change)="selectCity($event.target.value)">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Country</option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of countries" value={{c.id}}>{{c.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <label>Country</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s6 m3 l3">
    <select materialize="material_select" formControlName="city">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>city</option>
        <option *ngFor="let ci of cities" value={{ci.id}}>{{ci.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <label>City</label>
</div>
```

The component code, summarized:

```
countries = any[];
countrySelected = any;
cities = any[];

this.placeService.getPlaces().subscribe(data => this.countries = data);


  selectCity(value) {
    this.countrySelected= this.countries.find(o => o.id === value);    
    this.cities= this.countrySelected.city;  
  }
```

The method located in the service:

```
  getPlaces() {
    return this.http.get('assets/database/rac/places.json')
    .map( (res: Response) => res.json().country);
  }
```

Finally, the JSON file which is called:

```
{
"country": 
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Brazil",
            "city": [ { "id": "1", "name": "Rio Branco"}, 
                      { "id": "2", "name": "Xapuri"}, 
                      { "id": "3", "name": "Cruzeiro do Sul"} ] 
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Argentina",
            "city": [ { "id": "4", "name": "Buenos Aires"}, 
                      { "id": "5", "name": "Cordoba"}, 
                      { "id": "6", "name": "Rosario"} ] 
}]
```

Comment: Tried in stackblitz (removed styling)
Working fine here it seems: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pf1znf
Can you update on this?

Comment: hi, I've used the solution above adding [materializeSelectOptions]="cities" and worked fine! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using angular2-materialize, I believe you need to add the directive materializeSelectOptions, otherwise materialize doesn't track changes to options:

```
<select materialize="material_select" formControlName="city" [materializeSelectOptions]="cities">
```

As to why the first select works without that, can't say. Is there an *ngIf="countries" around all that?

As a side note, you're setting types as initial values. Should be:

```
countries: any[]; // = null
countrySelected: any;
cities: any[];
```

Comment: my friend you are saving my day. I add this [materializeSelectOptions]="cities" and worked fine. I really apreciate your attention

Comment: Happy to help :)